# Is it possible to verify that an error message does not briefly show at a certain stage of the Cypress test?

Tags: cypress

I have an application that requires some fields to be filled out before sending the form. When the fields are filled out and the submit button is pressed, a modal appears stating that this will send the information to the recipient. However, in Cypress I can also see an error message saying that "the form cannot be sent" is present. This can almost never be reproduced manually, so I guess that the speed of Cypress is what reveals it. However, on occasion, the user can see the red text flash by even though it doesn't show long enough to read the text.
The form is sent as it should be so it doesn't affect the functionality.

Is there any way to have Cypress verify that a specific text is never visible in a specific stage of a test?

This is a snippet from the DOM. The error message is not showing in this instance (I don't know how to produce it when running normally):

```html
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="button-wrapper">...</div>
  <div class="drCop-top-padding-section ng-hide" ng-show="model.showerror" style="">
    <dc-alert-message alert-severity="danger" class="alert-dialog-error" alert-message-id="error.failedtosend">
      <div ng-attr-id="{{alertId | uvDomIdFilter}}" class="alert alert-danger" ng-class="::{'alert-warning': alertSeverity === 'secrecy'}">
        <div class="alert-icon" ng-switch="::alertSeverity">
          <i ng-switch-when="danger" class="material-icons" style="">warning</i>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <span dynamic-label="" key="error.failedtosend" class="multiline">Could not send form. Try again later.</span>
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
      </div>
    </dc-alert-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the magic of [`MutationObserver`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). There is not a pre-made command to do this in Cypress as of yet [(related issue)](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3355).

This approach uses the following technique:

1. Create a MutationObserver that can set a flag to `true` if a certain `Node` is seen
2. Attach that MutationObserver to the application under test
3. Run your tests as usual
4. Check that the flag has not been set to `true`

Example code:

```js
let observedErrorMessage = false

cy.visit('index5.html')

// 1. initialize the MutationObserver with a callback
const observer = new MutationObserver((records) => {
  // this will be called for each added or removed
  // node to the DOM
  records.forEach((record) => {
    // addedNodes is a list of `Node` objects
    const { addedNodes } = record
    addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
      // you can use anything that works on a normal
      // HTMLElement here
      if (addedNode.className === 'error-message') {
        // we'll assert on this later
        observedErrorMessage = true
      }
    })
  })
})

// 2. hook up the MutationObserver to your app code
cy.document().then($document =>
  // $document is a reference to `window.document`
  // of the application under test
  observer.observe($document.body, {
    childList: true, // emit for add/remove nodes
    subtree: true    // emit for all nodes in tree
  })
)

// 3. run your tests here that cause the spurious
// page change
cy.wait(2000)

// 4. assert that the message has not been observed
cy.wrap().then(() => {
  // we wrap this in a callback so that
  // `observedErrorMessage` is only read after
  // the prior Cypress commands are complete
  expect(observedErrorMessage).to.be.false
})
```

Comment: That was an extensive example, thanks! However (and now I'm totally revealing my lack of knowledge in JS/HTML etc.), the element is present all along, it's just normally hidden. I updated my original question with an HTML snippet if that helps.

Comment: Hmm, you're using `ng-switch` to hide the element? If `ng-switch` just removes it from the DOM, then this should still work. Did you try it and it didn't work?